# How to allow manual workflow_dispatch only on specific branches?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow file, which allows a manual trigger using the `workflow_dispatch` event. GitHub offers a drop-down list to choose on which branch to run the workflow.

I was wondering if there is any way to **limit that option to a specific branch** (or specific branches).

Example of a workflow file with a `workflow_dispatch`:

```
name: A test workflow title
on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:
    # branches:    # *** This seems to not be supported! ***
      # - main

jobs:
  print-hello-world:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Print hello world
        run: echo "Hello world!"
```

Answer (score 14):

Using `if` you can add a step to fail a job if the workflow was triggered by `workflow_dispatch` on specific branches.

```
name: A test workflow title
on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  print-hello-world:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Fail if branch is not main
        if: github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' && github.ref != 'refs/heads/main'
        run: |
          echo "This workflow should not be triggered with workflow_dispatch on a branch other than main"
          exit 1

      - name: Print hello world
        run: echo "Hello world!"

      - name: Log github context
        run: echo "${{ toJSON(github) }}"
```

It's also possible to skip the job by placing the negative condition in the job-level:

```
jobs:
  print-hello-world:
    if: github.event_name != 'workflow_dispatch' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
    ...
```

Comment: This is good but it will only work if this piece of code is placed in all the branches. If someone creates a new branch and remove this part then workflow in that branch will not have this check

Comment: @R-JANA That's right, and a disadvantage of this solution. Did a quick check and I didn't find a way, as an organization owner, to limit the write access to developers to disallow them to edit the workflow files, or to run them on branches different than `main`. I know with classic tokens, it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do this is by using **Environment Protection Rules**.

1. Create an environment for your workflow file like `production` by going to **Settings** > **Environments**
2. After creating `production`, you will find the topmost section of `Deployment Branches` on clicking on `production` in the list of environments.
3. You should be able to see a button with the default option of `All Branches`. You can select either `Protected branches` or `Selected branches` with a matching pattern.

Add this environment to your workflow file under jobs like:

```
name: A test workflow title
on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  print-hello-world:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    environment: production
    steps:
      - name: Print hello world
        run: echo "Hello world!"
```

References: 
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#environment-protection-rules

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#creating-an-environment

Comment: That's interesting, but not blocking any developer from commenting out the `environment:` line in his branch and then dispatching it from his branch.
Though, if combining this with the VARIABLES and SECRETS feature, which can be set on a specific environment, a manager can prevent sensitive operations by exposing the variables and secrets only to a particular deployment.